# What is a "Big Box" (referenced in GT-3 mission transcripts)?

Tags: history

I randomly stumbled across [this old Gemini 3 mission transcript online](http://www.jsc.nasa.gov/history/mission_trans/GT03_TEC.PDF). On the last page, after splash-down, the crew begins corresponding with "Big Box 15" and "Big Box 14" — I'm assuming these are probably references to naval ships, such as the Intrepid, which ultimately retrieved the capsule and crew.

Is that correct — does "Big Box" refer to the recovery vehicles? What's the origin of the name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key letters "RA" adjacent to the lines make it clear that these are two recovery aircraft.

The transcript is also shown [here](http://gemini3.spacelog.org/page/00:04:51:40/).

I do not know the origin of the name, but I assume the aircraft are the helicopters that came from the carrier [USS Intrepid](http://www.intrepidmuseum.org/LatestNews/March-2014/The-Gemini-3-Recovery--49-Years-Ago-This-Week).

[image: picture of helicopter during a recovery mission]

Comment: http://spacelog.org ... Well, there goes my productivity for the day... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

They are fixed-wing aircraft, and the first to put jumpers in the water (via parachutes) as they arrived several minutes before the helicopters.

Molly Brown splashed down about 45-60 nautical miles short of target, because the capsule did not have the steerable lift expected during reentry.

I have been unable to locate information as to what type of airplane these were.